# hide the selection mark bar from a drop down

Tags: html, css, asp.net

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTesting" DataTextField="value" DataValueField="key" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTesting_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Well, this drop down list have only one single value. I would like, if possible, to hide the selection mark. Obviously, the easy and logical solution would be to change this dropdown list into a textbox. But, in the future, this drop down list may contain multiple options items.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found after a little searching

```
select {
    /*for firefox*/
    -moz-appearance: none;
    /*for chrome*/
    -webkit-appearance:none;
  }

/*for IE10*/
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```